# Docker build is using cache for COPY command even if my files have changed

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile that is as follow:

```
FROM node:14-alpine as frontend-builder
WORKDIR /app/frontend
COPY ./frontend .
ENV PATH ./node_modules/.bin/:$PATH
RUN set -ex; \
  yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production; \
  yarn cache clean; \
  yarn run build
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

I have changed one file in frontend folder and re-run the build and docker is using the cache...I know i can force to build with --no-cache but how can i tweak docker so it detects changes in my files instead of no-cache option ?

Comment: That should work without special setup.  Is the file you're changing excluded in a `.dockerignore` file, perhaps?

Comment: I also had this issue and latter noticed I had a conflicting file name in my build context. It gives no warning and was not using the one I was editing by default